# How to get all Custom Post Type Filtered by one Specific Taxonomy Term

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I have a custom Post Type called `Movies`, and an associated Taxonomy called `Genre`. Now I need to list all CPT(s) which are in Genre of 'Comedy' in my own custom page (regardless of WP parmalink mechanism)

Following code only returns the custom post type `moviesCPT`:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'moviesCPT', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new      WP_Query( $args ); 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
 $loop->the_post(); the_title(); 
echo '<div class="entry-content">'; the_content();
echo '</div>'; 
endwhile;
```

Can you please let me know how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify this when you make your query:

```
'genre' => 'comedy'
```

Where `genre` is the name of your taxonomy ( not the human readable version, but the internal slug ), and `comedy` is the slug of the term you want to filter by

Importantly, indent your query parameters, and put them each on their own line so that it's easy to read/type/change, a good editor will do this for you. You also need to do an `if( $loop->have_posts() )` to check that you got posts and handle things if none were found, and a `wp_reset_postdata` call to clean up at the end ( otherwise any calls you make will show the last movie in the loop, rather than the current post/page )

You can use the `tax_query` parameter for more complex queries, the details are in the codex under the `WP_Query` documentation

Comment: I will start to love these taxonomies.